# Cómo a partir de dataGridView generar un Excel de forma más rápida con C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicación en la cual en un dataGridView1 me muestra información de un procedimiento almacenado. Y yo, mediante un botón lo que hago es tomar esa información del dataGridView y la convierto a un Excel.

Hice un prueba con 1520 registros(filas) y se demora un poco (unos 5 minutos), sé que puede ser por la cantidad de información que tiene que convertir, pero quisiera saber si hay otra forma de hacerlo que sea más optima porque después voy a tener que traspasar más información a excel, este es mi código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
    fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
    if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
        aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
        hoja_trabajo =
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
        libros_trabajo.Close(true);
        aplicacion.Quit();
    }
}
```

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si desea exportar en excel el contenido de un GridView puede utilizar como recurso la clase **StringWriter**

```
public void exportarExcel()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=NombreArchivo.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }


    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        return;
    }
```

El rendimiento al momento de exportar el DataSet es mucho mejor.

Saludos.

Comment: ok, una consulta para este caso necesito agregar alguna referencia de excel? Porque actualmente con la que trabajo uso Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Debe utilizar la referencia **using System.IO;**

Comment: oka, voy a probar y te aviso

Comment: el Response, de dónde lo sacas? porque no me lo reconoce

Comment: El Response viene del **namespace System.Web.UI**  `public HttpResponse Response { get; }`

Comment: Funcionó, disculpa la demora. Muchas Gracias

Comment: El código refleja preocupación por la liberacion correcta del response pero el buffer y los recursos del stringWritter y HtmlTextWritter los dejas en el olvido. Imagino una mejor implementacion y manejo de estos objetos, puedes revisar en la documentación oficial ya que existen metodos que hacen el trabajo por ti (uno que otro using bien implementado tambien puede simplificar las cosas)